# Nucleotide Frequency - HOMER?

Tags: bash, homer

I'm trying to find the frequency of UA dinucleotide in a bed file. I want to convert the bed file to FASTA, count all the UA dinucleotides up, then divide by the total length of the FASTA file.

Also, I probably need to compare the value I get above to the background, but I'm not sure how to go about this?

I understand homer should do the counting for me and also create a background distribution for me. It looks like I need to build a basic motif file and give homer a bedfile of locations and motif file to find. However, I'm unsure of how to set this up.

Other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is it UA per BED interval (so per row), or total entries, or per chromosome/contig? Please provide reproducible in- and output for this question to make sense. I fear otherwise it will quickly get closed for lack of details and clarity.